# Using neural networks neuralnet in R to predict factor values

Tags: r, neural-network

I am using `neuralnet` package, use several inputs to predict an output.

Originally, my output is a factor variable, and I saw the error:

```
Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

When I converted the output to `numeric` variable, the error disappeared. Is there a way to neural network with factor output?

Comment: Without knowing more about your dataset, I would suggest you could try encoding the factors as separate 'indicator' variables. For example, if one variable was a Win/Loss/Draw factor, you could then encode this as 3 separate variables (Win/Loss/Draw), where the value each of these variables takes is either 0 or 1 to indicate which is the correct choice. Note - this is what happens 'behind the scenes' if you fit models such as a GLM in R, however, in neuralnet you need to be more explicity with what you want to do.

Answer (score 7):

I adapted code that I found at [this site](http://horicky.blogspot.de/2012/06/predictive-analytics-neuralnet-bayesian.html), which uses the iris dataset with the neuralnet package to predict iris species from the morphological data.

Without a reproducible example, I'm not sure if this applies to your case. The key here was to convert the factorial response level to its own binary variable. The prediction is a bit different than other models in R - you choose the factor level with the highest score.

#### Example code:

```
library(neuralnet)

# Make training and validation data
set.seed(1)
train <- sample(nrow(iris), nrow(iris)*0.5)
valid <- seq(nrow(iris))[-train]
iristrain <- iris[train,]
irisvalid <- iris[valid,]

# Binarize the categorical output
iristrain <- cbind(iristrain, iristrain$Species == 'setosa')
iristrain <- cbind(iristrain, iristrain$Species == 'versicolor')
iristrain <- cbind(iristrain, iristrain$Species == 'virginica')
names(iristrain)[6:8] <- c('setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica')

# Fit model
nn <- neuralnet(
  setosa+versicolor+virginica ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width,
  data=iristrain, 
  hidden=c(3)
)
plot(nn)
```

[image]

```
# Predict
comp <- compute(nn, irisvalid[-5])
pred.weights <- comp$net.result
idx <- apply(pred.weights, 1, which.max)
pred <- c('setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica')[idx]
table(pred, irisvalid$Species)

#pred         setosa versicolor virginica
#  setosa         23          0         0
#  versicolor      1         21         7
#  virginica       0          1        22
```

Comment: It looks very promising, I will try and let you know. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This might raise warnings:

```
nn <- neuralnet(
  setosa+versicolor+virginica ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width,
  data=iristrain, 
  hidden=c(3)
)
```

So replace it with:

```
nn <- neuralnet(
  setosa+versicolor+virginica ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width,
  data=iristrain, hidden = 3,lifesign = "full")
```

If this does not work:

```
comp <- compute(nn, irisvalid[-5])
```

then use

```
comp <- neuralnet::compute(nn, irisvalid[,1:4])
```